# Ranking probabilities of logistic regression models M1 and M2 taking confidence intervals in account

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, predictive-models, ranking

I have two models M1 and M2 and each models the probability of having cancer with logistic regression. M1 is based on independent variables IV1 measured on a given sample of individuals and M2 is based on another set of independent variables IV2 measured on another sample of individuals. Suppose now I want to rank all the individuals by the descending probability of having cancer.

What could be a good method that takes into account the confidence intervals of each probability outputted by M1 or M2? Intuitively I tend to think that I should rank higher an individual that has a probability of 0.39 with a small CI than another that has 0.40 with a very large CI but I don't know how to make this intuitive idea operational and objective.

Comment: To take into account estimation uncertainty, you could simulate (maybe using Bayesian logistic regression makes this easier) from the models, predict, many times and use the resulting fractions of cancer for the ranking?

Comment: I thought about something like that but wouldn't the result be inevitably to choose the individual with 0.40 before the one with 0.39 because the simulations would show higher fraction of cancer in the former than in the latter?

Comment: unless Bayesian logistic regression (which I don't know much) can reveal asymmetrical distributions maybe?

Comment: Maybe so, but if that is true then you have answered your own question: Just use the predicted probabilities for ranking. But, I wonder if there might be cases where some probs would be estimated with much less/larger precision than others, and if they are close to 0 or 1 ...